# can't access to sql server from remote client with windows authentification

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, remote-access

I've got windows server 2012 and windows 7 on virtual machine connected on the same network, I try to connnect to sql server database on windows server from windows 7 (windows server is member of my domain), but it's always show me this error : login from an untrusted domain, 
I connect with a user in my domain , I even tried with administrator
(trying to connect with sql authentification work perfectly)

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw66i.png)

Comment: Your server and the other system are on different domains and delegation/trust relationship is not present between the two domains.

Comment: To expand on the above - any network can be split into multiple domains. On your network, there are at least two different domains (check with your network people to identify all of the different domains and what machines are on which domain.) Different domains on the same network can be Trusted (so it would be okay to log in from that domain), but they don't have to be. Also talk with your network people about trust between the domains.

Comment: It's just for a school project both virtual machine are on my machine(192.168.4.254/24 192.168.4.20/24) ,i've got only one domain ,